# Do X when SignalR fails to use websockets

Tags: typescript, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to give a warning to an User when SignalR can't establish a Websocket Connection.
How can i find out if the Websocket Connection was blocked / if SignalR is using a different transport Method?

I'm using Asp.net Core SignalR and Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i find out if the Websocket Connection was blocked / if SignalR is using a different transport Method?

On SignalR JavaScript client, we can get the transport using this code snippet.

```
HubConnection.connection.transport.constructor.name
```

Test code

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
    .build();

//...

connection.start().then(function () {
    //...
    //get the transport

    console.log(connection.connection.transport.constructor.name);
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Test Result

*With WebSocket*

[image]

*With LongPolling*

[image]